# Probability that two natural number have n as gcd, give a certain distibution.

Tags: probability, number-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable that take values on $\mathbb{N}$,
Let $Y$ be an indipendent copies of $X$,
Let $P(X=n)=\frac{n^{-s}}{\zeta(s)}, \,\, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}n^{-s}$

**How can we prove that:
$P(gcd(X,Y)=n)=\frac{n^{-2s}}{\zeta(2s)}$**

What i do Is the following:
$P(gcd(X,Y)=n)=P([(\exists k \in \mathbb{N} : X=kn)\cap(\exists j \in \mathbb{N} : Y=jn)]\cap[k,j  \text{ coprime}])=P(\cup_{k,j \text{ coprime}}(X=nk\cap Y=jn))= \sum_{k,j \text{ coprime}}P(X=kn)P(Y=jn)$

The problem is essentially that it seems to me that, fixed k, i have to know the form of all coprime number less or equal to k in function of k.

Comment: There is no uniform way to choose a random element from $\mathbb N,$ so you either have to give us a distribution, or ask for a density measure (picking a pair of numbers from $1$ to $K$ and take the limit as $K\to\infty.$)

Comment: For a random variable with value on $\mathbb{N}$ give the distribution is equivalent to give $P(X=n)$ for all n, that exactly what i do in the third row.

Comment: Ah, you give the probability measure after you say $X$ is random natural number, and use the word "Let." The full sentence should be "Let $X$ be a random natural number **with** $P(X=m)=\cdots$ ." Also, don't use $n$ in two different ways - as $P(X=n)$ and $P(\gcd(X,Y)=n).$ These are two different ideas, and should have two different variables. In particular, the second is for a fixed $n$ while the first needs to be true for all $n.$

Comment: I see now that i wrote that X is a random value, i made a typing error, what i would ti say is that X Is an a random variable. Now i correct